# Is the phrase "the fact that" fixed?

Tags: grammar

It seems that the phrase "the fact that" is fixed, and we cannot substitute the word "fact" with others? E.g., we can say:

We made this decision based on the **fact** that he is one of the most the most popular scholars

But it would be ungrammatical to say:
We made this decision based on the **factor** that he is one of the most the most popular scholars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a cliche, but it is not fixed. Some other words that occur are *belief*, *observation*, and *understanding*.